# Reportportal with testng - how to set launch name during run time

Tags: testng, reportportal

I am looking for a way to set launch name during testng run. This is otherwise set in configuration (rp.launch). I need to set a custom launch name for every testng run. I am using agent-java-testng:4.0.0-BETA-1

I have tried the suggested alternative way but cannot locate the classes that are mentioned here - ConfigurationModule & TestNGAgentModule: https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-testNG

```
public class MyListener extends BaseTestNGListener {
    public MyListener() {
        super(Injector.create(Modules.combine(Modules.override(new ConfigurationModule())
                        .with(new Module() {
                            @Override
                            public void configure(Binder binder) {
                                Properties overrides = new Properties();
                                overrides.setProperty(ListenerProperty.UUID.getPropertyName(), "my crazy uuid");
                                PropertiesLoader propertiesLoader = PropertiesLoader.load();
                                propertiesLoader.overrideWith(overrides);
                                binder.bind(PropertiesLoader.class).toInstance(propertiesLoader);
                            }
                        }),
                new ReportPortalClientModule(),
                new TestNGAgentModule()
        )));
    }
}
```

I have a custom listener (ReportPortalTestNGListener) that I am adding to TestNG

TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
...
List mySuites = new ArrayList();
            mySuites.add(suite);

```
        ReportPortalTestNGListener listener = new ReportPortalTestNGListener();


        myTestNG.addListener((Object)listener);
        myTestNG.setUseDefaultListeners(false);

        // add test suite
        myTestNG.setXmlSuites(mySuites);
        myTestNG.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the description of issue is pretty difficult to understand due to formatting. 
Generally speaking, there are two options to set launch name on runtime:
1) Use environment/JVM variables. You should understand that variable should be set before ReportPortal's listener is initialized. 
2) Extend ReportPortal listener and pass launch time right to the request builder. Please, use the following [snippet as example](https://github.com/reportportal/example-java-TestNG/blob/master/logback/src/main/java/com/epam/rp/tests/extension/ParameterizedTest.java)

Comment: There is a challenge with setting environment variables for ReportPortal.

Comment: There is a challenge with setting environment variables for ReportPortal:
They all have a "." (dot) which is not supported in environment variables in linux environment.
For example: rp.endpoint , rp.uuid , rp.project . They all have dot in the variable name.

The original post of the code was from the examples listed in https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-testNG. I cannot get it to work :(